# Perform Band Ratio in GEE

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, aster, band-ratio

I was new in GIS and Google Earth Engine, i want to perform band ratio for mapping Ferric and Ferrous using ASTER L1T  Radiance.
I want to use band 2/1, 5/3, and 1/2.
How to perform it in Google Earth Engine?
I was tried but i don't know if this true or not.

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('ASTER/AST_L1T_003')
  .filterDate('2019-03-01', '2019-03-05')
  .filterBounds(Boundary);
Map.setCenter(107.62160048828126,-7.087318840287035, 12);
  Map.addLayer(dataset, {bands: ['B01', 'B02'], min: 0.0, max: 255.0}, 'ASTER1');
  Map.addLayer(dataset, {bands: ['B05', 'B3N'], min: 0.0, max: 255.0}, 'ASTER2');
  Map.addLayer(dataset, {bands: ['B02', 'B01'], min: 0.0, max: 255.0}, 'ASTER3');
  Map.addLayer(Boundary);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the User Guide, is excellent. [userguide](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/image_math)

First of all, your dataset is a ImageCollection not an image. So make sure you grab an image. There are different ways to compute band ratios. One of them is with expressions:

```
    var asterImage = ee.Image('ASTER/AST_L1T_003/20190304174953')
var bandRatio = asterImage.expression(
    'band1 / band2', {
      'band1': asterImage.select('B01'),
      'band2': asterImage.select('B02')});
```

Comment: But on my study area, it's more than one image. Is it possible to perform band ratio?
Thanks